# Phalcon route doesn't work

Tags: php, phalcon

My phalcon app has worked fine with standard MVC route convention.
However, I want to handle some variable via URL, then I have a route:

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->add("/timesheet/some/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]{2}}/{day:[0-9]{2}}", "Timesheet::some");
$router->add("/timesheet/getreport/{type:[a-z]}/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]{2}}/{day:[0-9]{2}}", "Timesheet::getreport");
$router->addPost("/user/auth", "User::auth");

return $router;
```

1. The first route (timesheet/some) worked fine, I can access to "year", "month" variable using `$year = $this->dispatcher->getParam("year");`, however the second route (timesheet/getreport) doesn't work. In this case, `$year = $this->dispatcher->getParam("year");` return null.
2. If I changed to

   $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

   $router->add("/:controller/:action", array(
       "controller" => 1,
       "action"     => 2,
   ));

   $router->add("/timesheet/some/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]{2}}/{day:[0-9]{2}}", "Timesheet::some");
   $router->addPost("/timesheet/getreport/{type:[a-z]}/{year:[0-9]+}/{month:[0-9]{2}}/{day:[0-9]{2}}", "Timesheet::getreport");
   $router->addPost("/user/auth", "User::auth");
   return $router;

every request will be routed to index/index. My project URL is localhost/fpas, and I already try both route /fpas/timesheet/some and /timesheet/some but it always redirect to index/index. What's wrong with it? (security/auth is commented out, so it's not result from authentication).

3. From my understand, the default route, $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(); only allow you to follow MVC convention, while $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false); do but you have to specific all routes for every controller/action. Can I keep the convention for most of the action, while have specific rewrite routes for some action. How can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->add("/", array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'setLanguage',
));

$router->add("/{language:[a-z]{2}}", array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'language' => 1
));
```

this one get's default routing just with language in the beginning

```
$router->add("/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action", array(
    'controller' => 2,
    'action' => 3,
    'language' => 1
));
```

with default action "index" when it's not in url

```
$router->add("/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller", array(
    'controller' => 2,
    'action' => 'index',
    'language' => 1
));
```

some other routes

```
$router->add("/{language:[a-z]{2}}/:controller/:action/:params", array(
    'controller' => 2,
    'action' => 3,
    'language' => 1,
    'params' => 4
));

$router->add("/{language:[a-z]{2}}/question/add/{type}", array(
    'language' => 1,
    'controller' => 'question',
    'action' => 'add',
));
```